# How to get the top 10 movies of a given genre with IMdbpy?

Tags: python, imdbpy

I am using IMdbpy and I want to extract the top ten movies from a given genre.

I have written following code:

```
code = "0133093"
  
# getting information
series = ia.get_movie(code)
  
# getting gerne of the series
genre = series.data['genres']
```

Based on the above output I am getting  Action and Sci-fi as a genre.

Now how to get top 10 movies of either action or Sci-fi or both genre.

I got this code but this code gives the top 20 movie and genres that differs. I want top 10 movies based on either Action or Sci-fi.

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()
top250 = ia.get_top250_movies()
for movie_count in range(0, 20):
    movie = ia.get_movie(top250[movie_count].movieID)
    print(movie['title'])print(*movie['genres'], sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()
code = "0133093"
  
genre  = ia.get_movie(code).data['genres']

top250 = ia.get_top250_movies()


i = 0
top_10_action_scifi = []
 
 
for movie in top250:
    if i < 10 and not set(genre).isdisjoint(set(ia.get_movie(movie.movieID).data['genres'])):
        top_10_action_scifi.append(movie.movieID)
        i = i + 1
        print(movie)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So this code will give movies having both Action and Sci-fi genres. Am I correct in my understanding? Suppose if I want to do either Action or Sci-fi then what tweak shall I make? I would appreciate it if you can help me understand what's happening in that if statement line?

Comment: One more question when I am using movie code 4925292 it is still giving me the same list.

Comment: Hi, the code will return a list with movies that match any genre in the genre list, which means it will return either action or sci-fi or both. If the genres of the code 4925292 are the same as 0133093, then yes it will give you the same list

Comment: @cmpunk, if the answer worked for you, then please accept it